# How to reduce memory footprint of t1.Micro Amazon AMI?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I recently launched Amazon Linux AMI 2012.09 (several tries) because of Amazon's 1 year free tier offer. However, its always running out of memory/RAM! How can I reduce the initial memory footprint of this AMI?

thanks!

Comment: You need to provide more information. Which services are you running? Which instance type are you running?

Comment: Sorry, after I launch the instance I'm installing LAMP for a Wordpress blog. I install LAMP using yum. But I just needed about an extra 50MB freed. There's plenty of tuning tips for LAMP Wordpress on the web including here so I've already applied many of those. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide more information, but there is some general steps you could take, such as installing low memory versions of stuff, such as mingetty. Here's a checklist that could be of use: http://stacklinux.com/discussion/4/how-to-strip-down-amazon-linux-ami-amazon-web-services-ec2/

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [faq#deletion]) since it is meaningless by itself and **target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future**. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The link is now dead. :-)